# CSS Search Bar Not Responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm making a responsive GitHub Homepage Clone (https://github.com/) with HTML and CSS before moving on to JS. I'm currently working on a search bar. However, when I narrow the screen from the left side, the search bar width stays the same, causing the search bar to leave the entire left navigation bar. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
P.S. Please view the code snippet at full page view

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #f6f8fa;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#left-menu {
    background-color: white;
    width: 25%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;    
}

#left-menu-items {
    margin: 40px 15px 300px 25px;
    width: 85%;
}

#left-menu input {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: solid 1px #e1e4e8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 8px 113px 8px 10px;
}

#left-menu input::placeholder {
    color: #d2d5d8;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/735c9ee1fa.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>GitHub Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="left-menu">
        <div id="left-menu-items">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Find a repository...">
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: CSS Issues are going to be hard with no reproducible example.. It might be worth making one, also formatting the question a little better, walls of text usually don't help anyone now the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The element I'm working on is the search bar that says "Find a
> repository..." In order to allow the box to stretch to the right, I've
> added a ton of padding.

Hi, Joshua.

In this case, asking a question with so many parts is hard to answer. If you can create a smaller example - it might help.

```
<aside class="sidebar">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Find  a repository">
</aside>
```

.

```
.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

input[type='search'] {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-style: innherit;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/smnovwqj/

From there - we can help you. You can always ask in the [CSS Discord](https://discord.gg/pFc6XmH) too.

HERE:  with the sidebar in tact: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/e6k8gydu/

Comment: If you need to "add padding to something" for reasons beyond 'padding' - then you can be sure that there is a better option. ; )

Comment: Alrighty I fixed up the question a little bit, so it's easier to read. Sorry about that I'm kinda new here. I'll make sure to word my questions better in the future :)

Comment: OK. I added another link. The key here - is to help you learn the solution / vs. just give you a snippet that 'works' for whatever mysterious reason.

Comment: These types of numbers are a sure bet that something needs to be reworked: padding: 8px 113px 8px 10px;

Comment: The padding was just to design the search box. I don't think it has anything to do with the solution.

Comment: really? Well, it does. The search box should just be 100% width - and not sized with arbitrary padding. That's exactly why it's breaking.

Comment: You are forcing the element to be bigger - by giving it padding. Like - giving your uncle 20 turkey dinners... and then wondering why his pants don't fit. ; )

Comment: Glad it did! Mostly everything... needs to be it's own 'component' - and then for the parent to determine it's boundaries/size - and position etc. If you can get into that mindset - you will be free!

Comment: Also - just for the future - you don't need to include the doctype and metadata and stuff. Just include the bare minimum stuff to recreate the situation. : ) !!!

Comment: Ok great. I also completely understand my issue with all that padding. Thanks for staying up this late to help :)

Comment: https://discord.gg/pFc6XmH - the discord is always there too

Comment: Sorry to ask. But is a discord sort of like a live subreddit?

Comment: it's just like "slack" - and yes - that's a good description. "live subreddit" (I like that)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want the search input to shrink and grow with the page.

To that end, you should use `max-width: 300px` along with `flex-grow: 1` on the `<input>`.

flex-grow tells the flex-box how to allocate space along its main axis (in this case, the X axis). The value you give it represents a fraction of the parent flex-box. So in this case, if give it the value `flex-grow: 1` it will take up as much space as it can, until it runs into another fixed with element, or another element that also has `flex-grow` set with a nonzero value.

`Max-width` simply tells the element how large it's allowed to get. You can obviously fine tune this by changing the value, but 300px seemed about right to me.

Put the two together and you no longer need your crazy padding. The input will shrink all the way down to nothing (if you want that to change you also add the `min-width` property)
and grow all the way up to 300px in this case.

You'll also also want to get rid of the `<p>` next to your text input. In this scenario, there's no reason at all to use a paragraph, as it has default styling that changes how it behaves. I would use a `<div>` instead.

After that I would get rid of the relative positioning on `nav div p{}` and just let flex-box do its magic. If you're trying to position an element in that way, a much better way is with `margin`. This is what margin is meant to be used for.

Sorry my answer isn't a more specific, but your question is a bit broad.

Comment: "You can obviously fine tune this by changing the value" - it might not be obvious